# Adyen create dropin fails with "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dropin')"

Tags: adyen

Trying to do a simple initial working example of Adyen Drop-in functionality.
I'm using package "@adyen/adyen-web" version 5.2.0 in a React app. (see code attached)

[image]

My backend API is built in .Net5 calling Adyen to create a session and returning id and sessionData correctly to frontend presented in "paymentSession".

Bu when code reaches the part checkout.create('dropin').mount(adyenElementRef.current) it fails with error in browser console: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dropin')".

[image]

I have no idea of why, and I followed the exact documentation on https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in

**UPDATE:**
I downgraded to version 4.1.0 and got it all to work by just changed to this code:

```
const checkout = new AdyenCheckout(adyenConfig)
            // Create an instance of Drop-in and mount it to the container you created.
            const dropinComponent = checkout.create('dropin').mount(adyenElementRef.current)
```

So something weird with latest version and the Promise-implementation?

Comment: Hey there! Would it be possible for you to make a reproducible example by any chance? I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Actually I downgraded to version 4.1.0 and got it to work only by changing the code to: const checkout = new AdyenCheckout(adyenConfig);
            const dropinComponent = checkout.create('dropin').mount(adyenElementRef.current);

Comment: Hey @persyl, I've upgraded the react example to use 5.x so you can have a reference : https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-react-online-payments/pull/8.  It's recommended not to use older versions if you can. 
Note you can still use the old flow even with 5.0 though. If you have a 4.x version working, upgrading the library should not create any issue at all

Comment: Thank you! I have now actually succeeded after different kind of found issues in my code, like versions etc. Your reference code will be of big help anyways, thank you!

Comment: Awesome. If you create an answer with your own solution and link to the repository to accept it that'd be great for others :)

Comment: From the error it seems that AdyenCheckout is being instantiated with the initial adyenConfig which is null
It would be nice if you can explain why do you have all these conditions in your useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really reproduce your example exactly, but I see in your comment that version 4.x seems to be working.

With version 5.0, the creation of `AdyenCheckout` is now asynchronous. Can you make sure this is not the source of the issue?

```
//version 4
const checkout = await AdyenCheckout(configuration);
// version 5
const checkout = AdyenCheckout(configuration);
```

See [the release notes](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/release-notes#releaseNote=2021-10-06-web-componentsdrop-in-5.0.0).

I recommend using the latest version of the integration if you are integrating today, it has quite a few new goodies.

Comment: Hum, I see you're already using a promise, so that actually shouldn't be the issue

Comment: Yes, strange, and I can not find any good examples out there using latest version....